# Предсказание перцептрона по сумме чисел во входящих секвенциях

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

Решаю стандартную задачу прогнозирования `0` или `1` по заданной секвенции. Как видно из входных данных, по значению первой позиции определяется выход.

```
# Perceptorn
# Sample         Input           Output
#  1         0   0  1               0
#  2         1   1  1               1
#  3         1   0  1               1
#  4         0   1  1               0


import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


training_inputs = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]])
training_outputs = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0]]).T


synaptic_weights = 2 * np.random.random((3, 1)) - 1
print('Weights: \n', synaptic_weights)
```

Вывод ->

```
Weights: 
 [[ 0.47501851]
 [-0.81516113]
 [ 0.01089572]]
```

Обучение перцептрона:

```
for i in range(20000):
input_layer = training_inputs
outputs = sigmoid(np.dot(input_layer, synaptic_weights))

err = training_outputs - outputs
delta = np.dot(input_layer.T, err * (outputs * (1 - outputs)))
synaptic_weights +=delta

print('WEights after training:\n', synaptic_weights)
print('Result, after training:\n', outputs)
```

Вывод ->

```
WEights after training:
 [[10.38047072]
 [-0.20694296]
 [-4.98423553]]
```

Result, after training:

```
[[0.00679865]
 [0.99445483]
 [0.99548673]
 [0.00553478]]
```

Предсказание:

```
# new situation
input_ = np.array([[1, 1, 0]])
output = sigmoid(np.dot(input_, synaptic_weights))
print(output)
```

Перцептрон справился с задачей и предсказал с вероятностью `0.99996183` что должна быть `1`. А как решить задачу с помощью все того же перцептрона, если хочу получать `1` или `0` в зависимости от суммы секвенции. Например (сумма, близкая к `100`):

```
(10, 20, 70) - 1, 
(1, 4, 5)    - 0, 
(100, 0, 0)  - 1.
```

Я подменял разные данные, игрался с количеством эпох, но удовлетворительный результат не получил.

Comment: Функции активации разные бывают,вроде гиперболический тангенс с параметрами сильный,есть еще биасы,вообще гиперпараметры.Если спрашиваете про данные - они должны в пределе [0, 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нормализуйте данные как (10, 20, 70)==(0,1, 0,2, 0,7)